# Find if a string exists within external files

Tags: expl3, external-files, strings

I'm trying to look for a way to determine if a particular text or string is present in external .tex files. It is like accepting a text input from a user and determining if that text can be found in your .tex files. For example, you may want to search for a title of an article, if it is present in your .tex or .bib files. Consider the following MWE.

```
%MWE
\documentclass{article}
%this is a temporary definition, just to declare the command.
\newcommand*{\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand}[4]{#1#2#3#4}
%first argument is the text/string to be searched.
%second argument is a list of external files that will be searched if the given string is present.
%third argument is the output if the string is found.
%fourth argument is the output if the stsring is not found.

\begin{document}

%I am trying to search for the text ``vibration'' if it is present inside the external files datafileone.tex, datafiletwo.tex, and datafilethree.tex.
%If the text can be found inside the external files, then ``The search phrase ... was found in ... '' will be printed in the pdf file together with the filename/s of the external file/s where the text was found. If not, then ``The search phrase was not found in any of the datafiles.'' will be printed.
%datafileone.tex contains the phrase ``amplitude of vibration''.
%datafiletwo.tex contains the phrase ``frequency of vibration''.
%datafilethree.tex contains the phrase ``instantaneous frequency and instantaneous amplitude''. (these are terms from my thesis :) )
%Therefore, if the macro \mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand is designed properly, it must output ``The search phrase `vibration' was found in datafileone.tex and datafiletwo.tex''

\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand%
{vibration}%This is the text or string to be searched in the given external files.
{%These are the external files.
datafileone.tex%
datafiletwo.tex%
datafilethree.tex%
}%
{The search phrase ... was found in ...}%datafileone.tex and/or datafiletwo.tex and/or datafilethree.tex
{The search phrase was not found in any of the datafiles.}%This is printed if the text is not found.

\end{document}
```

Phelype Oleinik used expl3 syntax and proposed the command  `\replacelineonce{<file>}{<search string>}{<replacement>}{<true code>}{<false code>}`
for find and replace, found in [How to replace a line in a file written by TeX' \write command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531955/how-to-replace-a-line-in-a-file-written-by-tex-write-command). The code is as follows (taken from the URL)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \replacelineonce { m m m m m }
  { \mountain_replace_once:nnnTF {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }
\NewDocumentCommand \replacelineall { m m m m m }
  { \mountain_replace_all:nnnTF {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }
\tl_new:N \l__mountain_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mountain_file_seq
\bool_new:N \l__mountain_replaced_bool
\ior_new:N \l__mountain_replace_ior
\iow_new:N \l__mountain_replace_iow
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \mountain_replace_once:nnn #1 #2 #3 { T, F, TF }
  { \__mountain_replace_aux:Nnnn \c_false_bool {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \mountain_replace_all:nnn #1 #2 #3 { T, F, TF }
  { \__mountain_replace_aux:Nnnn \c_true_bool {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mountain_replace_aux:Nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \ior_open:NnTF \l__mountain_replace_ior {#2}
      { \__mountain_replace_line:Nnnn #1 {#3} {#4} {#2} }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { mountain } { file-not-found } {#2}
        \prg_return_false:
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mountain_replace_line:Nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \seq_clear:N \l__mountain_file_seq
    \bool_set_false:N \l__mountain_replaced_bool
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l__mountain_replace_ior
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {##1} {#2}
          {
            \bool_set_true:N \l__mountain_replaced_bool
            \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mountain_file_seq {#3}
            \bool_if:NF #1
              { \ior_map_break:n { \__mountain_replace_skip: } }
          }
          { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mountain_file_seq {##1} }
      }
    \__mountain_replace_end:n {#4}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mountain_replace_skip:
  {
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l__mountain_replace_ior
      { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mountain_file_seq {##1} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mountain_replace_end:n #1
  {
    \ior_close:N \l__mountain_replace_ior
    \iow_open:Nn \l__mountain_replace_iow {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__mountain_file_seq
      { \iow_now:Nn \l__mountain_replace_iow {##1} }
    \iow_close:N \l__mountain_replace_iow
    \bool_if:NTF \l__mountain_replaced_bool
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { mountain } { file-not-found }
  { File~`#1'~not~found. }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=lists.tex
\immediate\write\tempfile{line1}
\immediate\write\tempfile{}
\immediate\write\tempfile{line2}
\immediate\write\tempfile{}
\immediate\write\tempfile{line2}
\immediate\write\tempfile{}
\immediate\write\tempfile{line2}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\replacelineonce{lists.tex}{line2}{line replaced}
  {Replaced once:}
  {Nothing replaced:}

\input{lists}
\bigskip

\replacelineall{lists.tex}{line2}{line replaced}
  {Replaced all:}
  {Nothing replaced:}

\input{lists}
\bigskip

\replacelineonce{lists.tex}{line2}{line replaced}
  {Replaced once:}
  {Nothing replaced:}

\input{lists}
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

My interest, though, is only to “find”, and not “find and replace”.

Another similar topic is [Find and replace in a document consisting of many 'included' files using \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536232/find-and-replace-in-a-document-consisting-of-many-included-files-using-includ)

Kindly seeking your help.

Comment: datafileone.tex% should be datafileone.tex (without %) so there will be a space between the filenames. same with datafiletwo.tex% which must be datafiletwo.tex and datafilethree.tex% which must be datafilethree.tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED to overcome limitations on input characters of certain catcodes.  Note in `datafileone.tex`, the word `vibration` is part of an argumented definition.  In `datafiletwo.tex`, the word `vibration` is part of a comment, which is also searched unless you comment out a particular line in the macro definition.  The file `datafilefour.tex` was added to provide a case where search terms are not to be found.

WARNING: In the current incarnation of the `readarray` package (which will be remedied in a future update), end-of-lines are always discarded during a `\readdef` and replaced with the value of `\readarraysepchar`, which is not the natural LaTeX way of reading end-of-lines.  This could affect searches where the search string spans multiple lines of input.

Arguments `#3` and `#4` of `\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand` are expected to, themselves, take 2 and 1 arguments, respectively, regardless of whether they do anything with them.  In the case of `#3` the two arguments passed include the search string, and the filename where the match was found.  In the case of `#4`, the argument passed is the search string.

EDITED to demonstrate an **OR** search, where multiple search strings can be simultaneously specified, with the `listofitems` **OR** comparitor `||`, as in `vibration||frequency`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{datafileone.tex}
\today \def\mashit#1{\textit{amplitude #1 of vibration}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{datafiletwo.tex}
frequency of something% REMEMBER TO CALL IT vibration
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{datafilethree.tex}
instantaneous frequency and instantaneous amplitude
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{datafilefour.tex}
none of the above
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems}
\readarraysepchar{ }% CURRENT readarray VERSION WILL INSERT THIS
% AUTOMATICALLY AFTER EACH INPUT RECORD IS READ (EVEN IF RECORD ENDS
% ON A MACRO OR `%')
\def\killcats{%
  \catcode`\#=12
  \catcode`\%=12 % COMMENT TO AVOID SEARCH OF COMMENTS
  \catcode`\\=12 
  \catcode`\{=12 
  \catcode`\}=12 }
\def\restorecats{%
  \catcode`\\=0 
  \catcode`\}=2 
  \catcode`\{=1 
  \catcode`\%=14
  \catcode`\#=6 }%

\newcommand*{\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand}[4]{%
  \def\findstatus{F}%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\filelist{#2}%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\filelist[]{%
    \killcats
    \expandafter\readdef\expandafter{\z}\tmpfile
    \restorecats
    \readlist\searchlist{\tmpfile}%
    \ifnum\searchlistlen>1\relax#3{#1}{\z}\def\findstatus{T}\fi
  }
  \if F\findstatus #4{#1}\fi
}
\newcommand\searchtrue[2]{The search phrase ``#1'' was found in #2.\par}
\newcommand\searchfalse[1]{The search phrase ``#1'' was not found in 
  any of the datafiles.\par}
\begin{document}
\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand%
{vibration}
{datafileone.tex, datafiletwo.tex, datafilethree.tex, datafilefour.tex}
{\searchtrue}{\searchfalse}

\bigskip
\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand%
{frequency}
{datafileone.tex, datafiletwo.tex, datafilethree.tex, datafilefour.tex}
{\searchtrue}{\searchfalse}

\bigskip
\mySearchforStringinExternalFilesCommand%
{vibration||frequency}
{datafileone.tex, datafiletwo.tex, datafilethree.tex, datafilefour.tex}
{\searchtrue}{\searchfalse}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir @stevenbsegletes. will study your solution

Comment: your solution has taken another level higher -- searching within comments. this is nice sir

Comment: can't imagine my latex codes without comments

Comment: @beethovengg14 And here is a bonus!  You can search for multiple things at once, separating the search field with `||` (the `listofitems` OR comparitor), as in argument `#1` being set as `vibration||amplitude`.

Comment: @beethovengg14 Please see my EDIT for a demonstration of this.

Comment: || is for OR. is there something for AND, NOR, NAND, like those in logic gates? :) this is really nice, searching for multiple keywords

Comment: @beethovengg14 Sorry, only OR.  The underlying purpose of the `listifitems` package is to break a delimited input string into a list array.  Typically, a delimiter might be a comma, but maybe you want it to be a comma OR a semicolon.  AND makes no sense in this context, even though the way I use the package here is to use the word "vibration" as a delimiter.  If the string contains this "delimiter" *n* times, the list will have *n* +1 elements.  If it does not contain the delimiter, the list only has one element.  I check the list length to determine the presence of the delimiter.

Comment: there is an extra "}" (closing brace) after \end{document}? maybe typo only

Comment: @beethovengg14 Thank you.  Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the file in a token list variable and do the check.

The third argument to `\lookfortextinfiles` is a template where `#1` stands for the file name with a match. The fourth argument, optional, is what to do in case of no match. I assume that you want to do something like `\input{#1}` or `\bibliography{#1}` if the file is a `.bib` file rather than just printing the list of file names with matches.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-one.tex}
amplitude of vibration
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-two.tex}
frequency of vibration
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-three.tex}
instantaneous frequency and instantaneous amplitude
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lookfortextinfiles}{m m +m +O{}}
 {% #1 = text to look for
  % #2 = list of files to look into
  % #3 = template
  % #4 = what to do in case of no match
  \beethovengg_lookfor:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\tl_new:N  \l__beethovengg_lookfor_file_tl
\seq_new:N \l__beethovengg_lookfor_match_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \beethovengg_lookfor:nnnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__beethovengg_lookfor_match_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \file_get:nnN { ##1 } { } \l__beethovengg_lookfor_file_tl
    \tl_if_in:VnT \l__beethovengg_lookfor_file_tl { #1 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__beethovengg_lookfor_match_seq { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:Nn \__beethoven_lookfor_use:n { #3 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__beethovengg_lookfor_match_seq \__beethoven_lookfor_use:n
  \seq_if_empty:NT \l__beethovengg_lookfor_match_seq { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lookfortextinfiles{vibration}{
  \jobname-one,
  \jobname-two,
  \jobname-three,
}{Found in #1\par}[Found in no file]

\bigskip

\lookfortextinfiles{frequency}{
  \jobname-one,
  \jobname-two,
  \jobname-three,
}{Found in #1\par}[Found in no file]

\bigskip

\lookfortextinfiles{foo}{
  \jobname-one,
  \jobname-two,
  \jobname-three,
}{Found in #1\par}[Found in no file]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir @egreg. will study your solution.

Comment: hoping that LaTeX 3 (expl3) will soon be released so i can study further the strange-looking commands :)

Comment: @beethovengg14 `expl3` is loaded as part of the LaTeX2e kernel

Comment: oh i see. thank you sir @JosephWright. i saw the expl3 documentation. it will take some time for me to digest it :) there are now underscores and colons in variable names

Comment: ever since i "shifted" to LaTeX since 2003, everything has been so logical, yet difficult to program at first.

Comment: hi sir @egreg, "I assume that you want to do something like \input{#1} or \bibliography{#1} if the file is a .bib file rather than just printing the list of file names with matches." this is not what I meant, but it is good idea though.

Comment: hi sir @egreg, i would like to thank you very much for your wonderful solution. it worked. it is simple/short, yet complicated (i still have to study/digest the meaning of all those expl3 syntax :( ) i guess im always after not just the solution but also understanding.

Comment: hi sir @egreg, kindly seeking your help again. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611605/appending-text-to-each-line-of-an-external-file-using-expl3-syntax