# Appending Text to Each Line of an External File Using expl3 Syntax

Tags: expl3, external-files, datatool, line, filesystem-access

Let us suppose I have an external questionfileone.tex file where each line of this external file represents a particular question text. It is something that I can use, for example, as a test database for my engineering students. Here is an illustrative example of that file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{questionfileone.tex}
1,"Engineering Question Text 1"
2,"Engineering Question Text 2"
3,"Engineering Question Text 3"
4,"Engineering Question Text 4"
5,"Engineering Question Text 5"
%and so on ..., hundreds, perhaps thousands of questions accumulated through the years ...
%and perhaps hundreds/thousands of external files containing thousands of questions per each external file
\end{filecontents*}
```

Note that the questions are numbered chronologically as 1, 2, 3, etc., and that each number and the question for that line is separated by a comma.

What I would desire is to put the answer for each question on the same line, that is, I would want my file to look like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{questionfileone.tex}
1,"Engineering Question Text 1","Answer Text"
2,"Engineering Question Text 2","Answer Text"
3,"Engineering Question Text 3","Answer Text"
4,"Engineering Question Text 4","Answer Text"
5,"Engineering Question Text 5","Answer Text"
\end{filecontents*}
```

Note that I have simply appended the string `,"Answer Text"` for each line of the external file. If there are only 5 lines in the external file, this could be done manually --- copy-paste system. However, if there are thousands of these lines, and perhaps hundreds/thousands of these external files (each file containing thousands of lines), it may be worthwhile to somehow automate the appending-text-per-line process.

Note that I still have to change the `Answer Text` for each line, since different questions will have different answers. But, at least, the placeholders are already there.

Note also that this could be done in MS Excel using the built-in concatenate function. However, I was thinking if it could be done using LaTeX, especially if there are numerous files involved.

Consider the following MWE:

```
%MWE
\documentclass{article}

%external file 1: questionfileone.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{questionfileone.tex}
1,"Engineering Question Text 1"
2,"Engineering Question Text 2"
3,"Engineering Question Text 3"
4,"Engineering Question Text 4"
5,"Engineering Question Text 5"
\end{filecontents*}

%external file 2: questionfiletwo.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{questionfiletwo.tex}
6,"Engineering Question Text 6"
7,"Engineering Question Text 7"
8,"Engineering Question Text 8"
9,"Engineering Question Text 9"
10,"Engineering Question Text 10"
\end{filecontents*}

%for declaration only
\newcommand*{\myAppendTextToEachLineOfExternalFile}[2]{#1#2}%
%#1 is the text to be appended to each line of the external files
%#2 are the list of external files

\begin{document}

\myAppendTextToEachLineOfExternalFile%
{,"Answer Text"}%
{%
questionfileone.tex,%
questionfiletwo.tex,%
}%
%This macro operation will append ``,"Answer Text"'' in each line of each of the external files questionfileone.tex and questionfiletwo.tex

\end{document}
```

My question, then, is: How do we design the macro `\myAppendTextToEachLineOfExternalFile{}` properly to achieve the desired result?

If it is possible, can we use `expl3` syntax in the macro?

Can we append text to each line of the external file *except the last blank line*?

Kindly seeking your help.

Comment: Do it outside of TeX.

Comment: Even outside of TeX you can still do it somewhat automatically by implementing it in Lua (if LuaTeX) or Python and write18 & sys_shell_now.